# How do I distinguish between a new and a synced bookmark?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension hooks chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener to detect new bookmarks. So far so good.

My problem comes when I have two browsers signed in to the same Google account. If I add a bookmark in browser-1, chrome.bookmarks.onCreated fires on browser-2 as the bookmark is synced from 1 to 2. How can I distinguish between a genuinely new bookmark (eg on browser-1) as opposed to an old bookmark which is being synced (eg on browser-2).

Comment: You could compare the current time with the value of the `dateAdded` or `dateGroupModified` properties of the `onCreated`'s second argument.

Comment: Nice idea. The only problem is that it requires that both browsers have the same time. If the clocks are adrift by the same number of seconds as the sync delay, I'll get a false positive. In the absence of a more deterministic solution (which I suspect doesn't exist), I'll probably run with this idea. Many thanks.